# pandas Optimizing many loops into one

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have multiple dfs with same columns. Here is the list of all dfs

`dfs = [df_14, df_15, df_16, df_17]`

Every dataframe looks like this for example,df_14:

| id | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 |
| 004 | 56 |
| 013 | 95 |
| 015 | 33 |

Next, df_15:

| Id | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 |
| 023 | 18 |
| 459 | 19 |
| 811 | 35 |

df_16:

| Id | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 93 |
| 114 | 56 |
| 232 | 0 |

df_17:

| Id | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 532 | 120 |
| 113 | 31 |
| 065 | 58 |
| 015 | 2 |

My code:

```
rows = [['532', 120],['113', 31], ['065', 58],['025', 2]]
for row in rows:
    df_14.loc[len(df_14)] = row
# and so on
```

The task is to append to lists of each month - the is which has 30-60 days and another separate list with id of clients which has 60-100 days.

```
#The result should be like this:
14_1:  ['004', '015']
14_2:  ['013']
15_1:  ['811']
```

I try to use f'strings on it. Something like:

```
abrreviations = ['14', '15','16', '17']
c = ['_1', '_2']
#Have wrote initializing loops like 
m_list=[]
for a in abrreviations:
    for cp in c:
        m_list.append(a+cp)
```

And the idea is using abbreviations in the loops with f'string or format. But don't know how to do it? Or can you offer another ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### This can help you

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'df_jan' : [['001', 0],['004', 56], ['013', 95],['015', 33]],
        'df_feb' : [['001', 0],['023', 18], ['459', 19],['811', 35]],
        'df_mar' : [['111', 93],['114', 56], ['232', 0]],
        'df_apr' : [['532', 120],['113', 31], ['065', 58],['025', 2]]}

dfs = {}
for df in data:
    dfs[df] = pd.DataFrame(data[df], columns=['id', 'days'])

months = {}

for df in dfs:
    months[df.replace('df_', '') + '_30'] = dfs[df][(dfs[df].days >= 30) & (dfs[df].days <= 60)].id.to_list()
    months[df.replace('df_', '') + '_90'] = dfs[df][(dfs[df].days >= 90) & (dfs[df].days <= 120)].id.to_list()
    
months

{'jan_30': ['004', '015'],
 'jan_90': ['013'],
 'feb_30': ['811'],
 'feb_90': [],
 'mar_30': ['114'],
 'mar_90': ['111'],
 'apr_30': ['113', '065'],
 'apr_90': ['532']}
```

###### In response to your comment:

I created the df inside the dictionary to simplify the creation of test data.

Your code can create the df in its own way ...

```
df_jan = ...
df_feb = ...
df_mar = ...
df_apr = ...
```

and to process them you create the dictionary ...

```
dfs = {
    'df_jan' : df_jan,
    'df_feb' : df_feb,
    'df_mar' : df_mar,
    'df_apr' : df_apr
}
```

run the loop

and you can assign results to your variables

and delete dictionaries

```
jan_30 = months['jan_30']
jan_90 = months['jan_90']
feb_30 = months['feb_30']
feb_90 = months['feb_90']
mar_30 = months['mar_30']
mar_90 = months['mar_90']
apr_30 = months['apr_30']
apr_90 = months['apr_90']

del dfs, months
```

Comment: Thank you, works good. Could you help me, suppose my dfs has many rows(like 10000), is this method going to work this well? Should i build dictionaries?

Comment: You don't need to build the df inside the dictionaries. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#let first create a list containing all the dataframe's

all_df=[df_jan, df_feb, df_mar, df_apr, df_may, df_jun, df_jul, df_aug, df_sep, df_oct, df_nov, df_dec]

#create 2 lists for storing the id values of 30-60 range and 90-120 range

list_30,list_90=[],[]

#1 nested for loop for handling all data frames

for cur_df in all_df:
    for id,days in zip(cur_df['Id'],cur_df['Days']):
        if(30<=days<=60):
            list_30.append(id)
        elif(90<=days<=120):
            list_90.append(id)

#Now list_30 and list_90 contains the corresponding id values in that range
```

Hope the answer helps :)

Comment: Thank you. But I need the ids of each month dataframes divided into corresponding lists. Like jan_30 = [ '001', '015'],jan_90 = [ '013'], feb_30 =  [ '811']